# Comparator is referred to as both an Object and an Interface

Tags: java, import, interface, comparator

I realize not understanding this might show a deeper issue in my understanding of Java, but when checking java se docs it does state Comparator is an Interface. Then when I create an 'comparator' object, I can only do it because I import the java.util.Comparator.

But given an Interface does not define methods AND interfaces don't have constructor (or do they..?), how can I instantiate a comparator object? Where is the defined method coming from?

Comment: Please show the code you used to create the `Comparator`.

Comment: Well either you create an instance of a class that already implements it, or you use an anonymous class. I don't quite follow what you're asking - do you understand interfaces in general, and there's something specific about `Comparator` that's confusing you, or are you unsure about interfaces in general?

Comment: "an interface does not define methods", an interface can define (concrete default) methods. actually, you don't just "import" the type, you must implement it as well

Comment: `Comparator` is an interface, "_a_ `Comparator`" is an object implementing that interface.

Comment: An interfaces doesn't have a constructor, but once you implement an interface, the class you create to do so has one. Even when you don't see an explicit class definition: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html - there is always sth like `class Foo implements SomeInterface` in the background and instances of such classes are created

Comment: Right so when I go Comparator<> abc  = new Comparator<>() what is happening

Comment: while only importing java.util.comparator, and not defining any method from the interface

Comment: @J.C Are you sure that works? On my machine, that line creates a compiler error.

Answer (score 0):

java.uti.Comparator is an interface. Interfaces cannot be instantiated—they can only be implemented by classes or extended by other interfaces.

If a class claims to implement an interface, all methods defined by that interface must appear in its source code before the class can successfully compile.

For given Type T(T is the class type of objects that needs to be compared) , unlike any other object instantiation, usually, an anonymous class that implements the comparator is instantiated, and not the interface itself. This is  like any other object and its of Type Comparator, so can be passed as an argument to Collections.sort or Arrays.sort methods.

```
 Comparator<T> c = new Comparator<T>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(T o1, T o2) {
            return 0;
        }
 };
```